# C++ Array of Objects with a copy constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

From the code below being compiled in CodeBlocks I'm getting errors of the this type:

```
 no matching function for call to 'student::student(student)' candidates are:
 student::student(student&)
     no known conversion for argument 1 from 'student' to 'student&'
 student::student(std::string, int, double, float)
     candidate expects 4 arguments, 1 provided
```

I'm guessing that somehow the C++ compiler is implementing the copy constructor in the array definition. But I can't seem to find a way around it. I need both constructors in my program and I need to initialize the array elements through a constructor. Please provide a solution that will work on C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class student{
    string name;
    int rollno;
    double marks;
    float per;
    /// Constructors
    student(string n, int r, double m, float p){
        name = n;
        rollno = r;
        marks = m;
        per = p;
    }
    student(student& s){
        name = s.name;
        rollno = s.rollno;
        marks = s.marks;
        per = s.per;
    }
};

int main(){
    student arrays[] = { student("Anas Ayubi", 80, 980, 980/1100),
                    student("Zainab Ashraf", 78, 990, 990/1100 ),
                    student("Wali Ahmed", 28, 890, 890/1100) };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
student(student& s){
```

Your copy constructor takes its argument by non-const reference. Non-const references cannot bind to rvalues. You then go on to try and create copies of rvalues:

```
student arrays[] = { student("Anas Ayubi", 80, 980, 980/1100),
                student("Zainab Ashraf", 78, 990, 990/1100 ),
                student("Wali Ahmed", 28, 890, 890/1100) };
```

The easy fix for this is to declare the copy constructor to take a reference-to-const, which *can* bind to rvalues:

```
student (const student& s){
```

Note that in `980/1100` you get integer division instead of floating point division, so you'll just get `0`. To fix this, force those `int`s to be `double`s: `980.0/1100`.

Incidentally, in C++11 you can simplify your array initialization like so:

```
student arrays[] = { {"Anas Ayubi", 80, 980, 980.0/1100},
                     {"Zainab Ashraf", 78, 990, 990.0/1100},
                     {"Wali Ahmed", 28, 890, 890.0/1100} };
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!! When I try to display the 'per' field in the program of elements in the array, it displays the value 0. Why is that happening?

Comment: @AnasAyubi `980` and `1100` are both `int`s, so integer division occurs rather than floating point division. You probably want something like `980.0/1100`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `student(const student& s)` - note the **const** - the proper signature of a copy constructor.

This is because you're attempting to bind temporaries to references, in which case const references are required.

Comment: What do you mean by a temporary?

Comment: `student(/*...*/)` creates a temporary object which is used to populate the array by copying it.

Comment: Isn't that a really inefficient way of storing objects in an array? Can we avoid the copying somehow?

Comment: It would be if we didn't have [copy elision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization), which will prevent the copying for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor should take its parameter by `const` reference, so it can bind to the temporaries you provide.